# What is best practice for using coroutines in KMM with ios?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm exploring the usage of coroutines in a Decompose ComponentContext for managing asynchronous tasks in a Kotlin project. In Android, we commonly use the following pattern to launch a coroutine on the IO dispatcher:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    // Some long-running task
}
```

Now, I'm working with Decompose, and I want to integrate similar coroutine behavior within a SplashScreenComponent, ensuring that the coroutine is tied to the component's lifecycle and behaves similarly to viewModelScope in Android's ViewModel. Here's a simplified version of my component:

```
import com.arkivanov.decompose.ComponentContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class SplashScreenComponent(
    componentContext: ComponentContext,
    private val settings: Settings,
    private val networkRepository: NetworkRepository,
    private val navigateTo: (RootComponent.Configuration) -> Unit
): ComponentContext by componentContext {

    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val loading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    private val _error = MutableStateFlow("")
    val error = _error.asStateFlow()

    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            // How can I properly tie this coroutine to the ComponentContext's lifecycle?
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone guide me on how to correctly tie this coroutine to the Decompose ComponentContext's lifecycle, ensuring that the coroutine is cancelled when the component's screen is destroyed, similar to the behavior of viewModelScope in Android's ViewModel? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose `ComponentContext` implements the `LifecycleOwner` interface, so you have access to `Lifecycle`. Both interfaces are provided by the Essenty library.

Since Essenty `v2.0.0-alpha01` you can add coroutines extensions to your project.

```
implementation "com.arkivanov.essenty:lifecycle-coroutines:<version>"
```

Then you can use it as follows.

```kotlin
import com.arkivanov.decompose.ComponentContext
import com.arkivanov.essenty.lifecycle.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext

class SomeComponent(
  componentContext: ComponentContext,
  mainContext: CoroutineContext,
  private val ioContext: CoroutineContext,
) : ComponentContext by componentContext {

  // The scope is automatically cancelled when the component is destroyed
  private val scope = coroutineScope(mainContext + SupervisorJob())

  init {
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Prior to Essenty `v2.0.0-alpha01` you can write the extensions manually.

```kotlin
import com.arkivanov.essenty.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import com.arkivanov.essenty.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import com.arkivanov.essenty.lifecycle.doOnDestroy
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.cancel
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext

fun CoroutineScope(context: CoroutineContext, lifecycle: Lifecycle): CoroutineScope {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(context)
    lifecycle.doOnDestroy(scope::cancel)
    return scope
}

fun LifecycleOwner.coroutineScope(context: CoroutineContext): CoroutineScope =
    CoroutineScope(context, lifecycle)
```

You can also check the [docs](https://arkivanov.github.io/Decompose/component/scopes/) for more information.